# jquery checkbox attr change seems not to work

Tags: checkbox, attr, jquery-1.5

Does anyone have any idea why this code seems not to work?
What am I doing wrong?

JQuery 1.5.1 is used.

JS code:

```
$('#search_filters #discipline a').click(function(){

    var checkbox = $(this).next(':checkbox');

    if (checkbox.attr('checked')) {
        checkbox.attr("checked", true);
    } else {
        checkbox.attr("checked", false);
    }

    $(this).children('img').toggleClass("active");

    return false;
});
```

HTML:

```
<li>
    <a href="#">
        <img class="inactive" alt="Football" src="/images/disciplines/e9bc7681813110c/thumb.png">
    </a>
    <input type="checkbox" name="search_discipline[7]" value="1" class="search_discipline">
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this myself. It seems in jQuery 1.5.1 and 1.5.2 setting the `checked` attribute is a bit buggy. I had better luck with `$(':checkbox').val(boolean)` (which is even a bit easier).

Update: after some digging, it seems the webkit inspector doesn't actually show the `checked` attribute in the DOM, but jQuery reads/writes it properly. Very odd. Serves me right for using the nightly webkit builds for dev.

Answer (score 1):

The value of a "checked" attribute should be "checked":

```
if (checkbox.is(':checked'))
{
    checkbox.attr("checked", "checked");
} else {
    checkbox.removeAttr("checked");
}
```

Comment: Not so. Either will work. Check out: http://jsfiddle.net/nbjV5/. In fact, if you `alert($("#test1").attr("checked"));` you will get 'true' or 'false'

Answer (score 1):

Just two helpful ideas to check the change for attributes:

- Write the plain HTML first, without Javascript. Did it work? If so, then write it with JS
- If you had modified an html tag recall the attribute itself, so you can check that your code had been executed well. E. g. `alert($({your target object}).attr({the attribute  which added}));`

That's what I do in the most cases.

Comment: addind alert() to:  if (checkbox.attr('checked')) return correct value (true / false)

Comment: I do not adding an 'alert()'. It is a seperate code line. For example 'alert($("search_discipline[7]").attr("type"))' will show me the value of tag attribute 'name'. If not, the manupulation of 'name' wasn't successful. This way is just a test to verify my code before.

Answer (score 0):

Some pointers:

1. `$('#search_filters #discipline a')` will be selecting all `a` elements that descend from `#discipline` that descend from `#search_filters`. Is this what you indend?
2. Are you remembering that `.next()` returns a sibling.
3. What happens if you remove the `href='#'`?
4. Does your click event even fire?

Comment: 1. yes
2. yes
3. same as witf href
4. yes

running script from FireBug console seems to work fine

Comment: What how many objects are there in the `checkbox` jQuery collection. (Inspect `.length` property). Also, it might be worth including the HTML that contains the `#search_filters` and `#discipline` IDs